AWS cloudformation error: Template error: Mapping named '1234567890' is not present in the 'Mappings' section of template
I'm relatively new to CloudFormation templates, and I'm encountering an issue while deploying an application onto AWS Lambda. The error message I'm receiving is:
I do have a mapping named '1234567890' in my template, but it seems like CloudFormation isn't able to locate it within the 'Mappings' section.
Here's a error which I'm facing:
[2024-05-02T01:40:39.915Z] - clause-recommend-lambda: Template error: Mapping named '1234567890' is not present in the 'Mappings' section of template.. Rollback requested by user.
20:41:11  
20:41:11  [2024-05-02T01:40:39.719Z] - clause-recommend-lambda: Template error: Mapping named '1234567890' is not present in the 'Mappings' section of template.
20:41:11  
20:41:11  [2024-05-02T01:40:36.340Z] - clause-recommend-lambda: User Initiated

Here is the Screenshot of my Mappings:

Here is the Screenshot of my FindinMap:

I'm unsure why CloudFormation is unable to find the mapping even though it's clearly defined in the template. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I tried:

Double-checked the CloudFormation template to ensure that the mapping named '1234567890' is correctly defined within the 'Mappings' section.
Verified the indentation and syntax of the mapping to ensure it conforms to YAML syntax requirements.
Tried deploying the CloudFormation stack multiple times to see if the issue persists.
Searched through AWS documentation and online forums to find similar issues and their resolutions.

What I was expecting:
I expected the CloudFormation deployment to succeed without any errors since the mapping '1234567890' is clearly defined in the template. My understanding was that CloudFormation would be able to locate and utilize the specified mapping during the deployment process.
However, despite these efforts, the issue persists, and CloudFormation continues to throw the error indicating that the mapping named '1234567890' is not present in the 'Mappings' section of the template.
I'm still searching for a solution or any insights into why CloudFormation is unable to recognize the mapping. Any further assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
